# How can I edit the POP!_OS super Launcher to change the text color for hovered elements?

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome, gtk4

I need to find the class or id of the launcher element then I can start tinkering.

Going to look on the POP!_OS GTK4 theme now and see if I can make sense of the CSS. It would be useful to have a tool to observe each element in the shell.

Tried reading through the CSS files but it is a bit confusing with out a inspect tool.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGQ74.png)